# Redirect https not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, redirect

I have a site which is configured to run on https:
https://www.domain.com.au/

I added the following to htaccess right at the top to redirect all non-https queries:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But, when I access http://www.domain.com.au/ it doesn't redirect as expected an instead I get a 302 redirect to a page that says:

> Found
>
> The document has moved here.
>
> Additionally, a 302 Found error was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request.

"here" is just a link to the same http URL in the address bar

- I was using cloudflare so I have grey clouded the domain to remove
  additional confusion and it's been switched off for a day now.
- It's a WordPress site and I have W3TC installed which I have also deactivated to remove confusion

I don't know where to look or how to debug? Any advice on where to start looking would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need to add the [L,R=301] flags to your rule?

Also - you can achieve this within CloudFlare automatically by enabling "Always use HTTPS" (if you have an active CloudFlare SSL certificate) and the 'orange cloud' enabled.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I've had all sorts of issues with cloudflare and websites so I like to get them functioning exactly as required BEFORE turning on cloudflare and introducing additional problem layers...